# Exchanging messages between two processes in Erlang

Tags: concurrency, erlang

Hi I'm learning Erlang and in the process I'm trying to do the exercises from the [Erlang execises page](http://www.erlang.org/course/exercises.html). In particular I'm doing the problem where I have to create a function that creates two processes that send M messages to the other and then die. I'm having trouble with it, this my code:

```
-module(roundtrip).
-export([talk/1]).

talk(M) ->
    init(M).

init(M) ->
    P1 = start(M),
    P2 = start(M),
    P2 ! {P1, a_message}.

myProc(M) ->
    if M =:= 0 ->
        io:format("Bye cruel world!~n")
    end,
    receive
        {From, a_message} ->
            From ! {self(), a_message},
            myProc(M-1);
        _ -> 
            io:format("I don't understand~n"),
            myProc(M)

    end.

start(M) ->
    spawn(?MODULE, myProc, [M]).
```

I get when I call the talk the following errors:

> =ERROR REPORT==== 11-Nov-2013::21:21:00 === Error in process <0.46.0> with exit value: {undef,[{roundtrip,proc,"\n",[]}]}
>
> =ERROR REPORT==== 11-Nov-2013::21:21:00 === Error in process <0.47.0> with exit value: {undef,[{roundtrip,proc,"\n",[]}]}

I'm going around it but I can't figure out what's the problem...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use `spawn/3` you need to export `myProc`.

Another problem is that your if condition does not cover the other possibility when `M =/= 0`. I'd do it like this:

```
-module(roundtrip).

-export([talk/1]).

talk(M) ->
    init(M).

init(M) ->
    P1 = start(M),
    P2 = start(M),
    P2 ! {P1, a_message}.

myProc(M) ->
    case M of
        0 ->
            io:format("Bye cruel world!~n");
        _ ->
            receive
                {From, a_message} ->
                    From ! {self(), a_message},
                    io:format("~p ~p~n", [self(), M]),
                    myProc(M-1);
                _ ->
                    io:format("I don't understand~n"),
                    myProc(M)

            end
    end.

start(M) ->
    spawn(fun() -> myProc(M) end).
```

Note that I used `case` instead of `if` and `spawn/1` instead of `spawn/3`.

Comment: Could you explain me why do I need to export myProc if I use spawn/3? I thought I needed to export whatever I use outside of the module. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doing a `spawn` creates a new process with its own context so in that process you are no longer inside your module and calling the function from "outside". Hence it needs to be exported.

Answer (score 3):

You need to export `myProc/1` function. Or you can use `spawn/1`:

```
start(M) ->
   spawn(fun() -> myProc(M) end).
```